# StringReplace em todas as ocorrências

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de substituir todas as `\` por `/` no meu edit, mas ele só funciona para a primeira ocorrência com o seguinte código:

```
Edit1.text := '"'+ StringReplace(Edit1.text, '\', '/', []) + '"';
```

Como fazer para substituir todas?

Aproveitando, o resultado seria algo parecido com

```
"C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/BD Demo/Alta Cruz/AltaCruz_c/"
```

como retirar a ultima `/` após o AltaCruz_c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve passar a flag rfReplaceAll como consta na [documentação](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StringReplace)

StringReplace(Edit1.text, '\', '/', [rfReplaceAll]);